# Multiple threads to read and import files in a directory

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I have a Java program to do 2 steps:

1. Read files in a directory recursively with multiple threads (10
   threads)
2. Send these files to a server by HTTP Post

It seems that the first step works well, but the second sends always the same file 10 times.

How to correct this error?

Here is my log:

```
Import file: 2005_1.xml
Import file: 2005_7.xml
Import file: 2005_6.xml
Import file: 2005_10.xml
Import file: 2005_5.xml
Import file: 2005_11.xml
Import file: 2005_8.xml
Import file: 2005_2.xml
Import file: 2005_3.xml
Import file: 2005_4.xml

Result: {"fileName":"2005_4.xml"
Result: {"fileName":"2005_4.xml"
...

Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400  [
Import file: 2005_9.xml
Result: {"fileName":"2005_4.xml"
...
Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200  [
Result: {"fileName":"2005_4.xml"

Response: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200  [
Result: {"fileName":"2005_9.xml"
```

And my code:
Read files in a directory with multiple threads:

```
public void listSendFilesMultiThread(final File folder) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, getThreadFactory());

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            Runnable r;
            r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                        listSendFilesMultiThread(fileEntry);
                    } else {
                        GetThread thread = new GetThread(fileEntry, errorFilesDestDir);

                        // start the thread
                        thread.start();

                        // join the threads
                        try {
                            thread.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("InterruptedException: " + e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            service.execute(r);
        }
    }
```

Send files by HTTP Post:

```
static class GetThread extends Thread {

        private final CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient;
        private final File file;
        private final String errorFilesDestDir;
        private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
        private MultipartEntityBuilder builder;

        public GetThread(File file, String errorFilesDestDir) {
            cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();

            this.file = file;
            this.errorFilesDestDir = errorFilesDestDir;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
                    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
                    // we should create a new builder per file
                    builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                    builder.addPart("xmlFile", fileBody);
                    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
                    request.setEntity(entity);

                    LOGGER.info("Import file: " + file.getName());
                    CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(request);
                    LOGGER.info("Response: {}", response.toString());

                    try {
                        entity = response.getEntity();
                        printInfo(response, entity);
                    } finally {
                        response.close();
                        closeableHttpClient.close();
                        cm.close();
                    }

                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                } else if (file.length() == 0) {
                    LOGGER.error("The import XML file is empty: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    Files.copy(file.toPath(), new File(errorFilesDestDir + file.getName()).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("The import XML file doesn't exist");
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Handle protocol errors
                LOGGER.error("ClientProtocolException: " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle I/O errors
                LOGGER.error("IOException: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection eviction policy

```
public static class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {

        private final HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr;
        private volatile boolean shutdown;

        public IdleConnectionMonitorThread(HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr) {
            super();
            this.connMgr = connMgr;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!shutdown) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(5000);
                        // Close expired connections
                        connMgr.closeExpiredConnections();
                        // Optionally, close connections
                        // that have been idle longer than 30 sec
                        connMgr.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void shutdown() {
            shutdown = true;
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I inspired the code in this link:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e639

Comment: The code in `listSendFilesMultiThread` does not make a lot of sense to me - why do you start a new Thread inside a `Runnable` that will be executed in parallel anyway, just to join it again immediately?

Comment: You are reason. Shall I put all files in a list and read them one by one with threads ?

Comment: You should use runnable object to define ur tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use producer and consumer pattern to simplify the code. One thread or several (one should be enough as it is not doing any processing) will use your logic and find the files to be uploaded. Next, it will place them in the queue. Start as many consumers as you wish to read the records from the queue and upload them to the server. https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer
The consumers will have the logic to read the file from disk and upload to the server.

Comment: There are 2 million of small files (10k to 2M) to upload to the server, one task takes 1 second. The solution with a queue is efficient?

Comment: First, 2 million is really nothing the real problem depends on your SLA. We have systems processing millions of records every hour, in multiple servers with multiple cores. In fact, when you mean efficiency, I would say, a queue either in a small scale like an in memory blocking queue, or in a large scale with multiple servers and a message queue system (like rabbit) is one of the few ways to build a reliable system. You can have reliability in concurrent applications with immutability and messaging only.

Comment: I succeed to correct the function listSendFilesMultiThread, with the help of the article: https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are running your 10 threads without any separation exclusion - if one thread processes one directory, another thread should not process the same folder. It means they are doing exactly the same work. You should make sure a thread doesn't start processing already visited directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `request` you are using in the `run()`-method of your `GetThread` is not mentioned anywhere else. As this is probably an inner class (as indicated by the static keyword), I guess that this is some field of the containing class and therefore shared among all threads.

As access to this global variable is not synchronized, the outcome of the overall operation is unpredictable.

Each thread should have its own instance of request. Keeping a glogal reference to a request-Object is almost never a good idea - it can lead to other problems as well, as Application Containers (for example Tomcat) sometimes have a pool of such Objects as well as the underlying resources (Connection Objects etc.) that may get reused later.

---

That said, in this case you are very likely IO bound anyway (i.e. limited by disk speed and upload bandwith, not by processing power) and don't gain anything by multithreading at all. I would use a single threaded solution here.

Comment: You are right, GetThread is an inner class. request is a global variable.